# Trying to compile OpenGL 4 Helloworld in CLion+CMake+MinGW on Windows. "undefined reference to `_imp____glewCreateShader' " errors

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, mingw32, clion

Googling aroung told me it was "wrong VS libraries" but when tried to use **glew-1.5.4-mingw32** and **libgluew32.a** instead of **glew32.lib** (and same done to glut) nothing changed.

**main.cpp** got from project on VS2012, attaching same libs, so it may not be wrong.

Some files I use to make:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(HelloGL)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

add_executable(HelloGL main.cpp)

set(LIBS_DIR D:/libs)

set(GLEW_ROOT_DIR ${LIBS_DIR}/glew-1.5.4-mingw32 )
set(GLUT_ROOT_DIR ${LIBS_DIR}/glut-3.7.6-src/glut-3.7.6 )

set(GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS ${GLEW_ROOT_DIR}/include)
set(GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS ${GLUT_ROOT_DIR}/include)

set(GLEW_LIBRARY ${GLEW_ROOT_DIR}/lib/libglew32.a)
set(GLUT_LIBRARY ${GLUT_ROOT_DIR}/lib/glut/libglut32.a)


include_directories( ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

target_link_libraries(HelloGL ${GLEW_LIBRARY} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} )
```

Part of LOG:

```
 "D:\Tools\CLion 140.569.17\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Alexey\.clion10\system\cmake\generated\dc6fcb22\dc6fcb22\Debug --target HelloGL -- -j 8
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Alexey/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/dc6fcb22/dc6fcb22/Debug
    Linking CXX executable HelloGL.exe
    CMakeFiles\HelloGL.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `Z11LoadShadersPKcS0_':
    D:/Projects/CPP/HelloGL/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `_imp____glewCreateShader'
    D:/Projects/CPP/HelloGL/main.cpp:20: undefined reference to `_imp____glewCreateShader'
    D:/Projects/CPP/HelloGL/main.cpp:56: undefined reference to `_imp____glewShaderSource'
    D:/Projects/CPP/HelloGL/main.cpp:57: undefined reference to `_imp____glewCompileShader'
    D:/Projects/CPP/HelloGL/main.cpp:60: undefined reference to `_imp____glewGetShaderiv'
    D:/Projects/CPP/HelloGL/main.cpp:61: undefined reference to `_imp____glewGetShaderiv'
    D:/Projects/CPP/HelloGL/main.cpp:64: undefined reference to `_imp____glewGetShaderInfoLog'
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this line to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_definitions(-DGLEW_STATIC)
```

It seems that you are trying to link `GLEW` statically but you didn't define `GLEW_STATIC`

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile GLEW yourself?

Generally the library called `glew32` is dynamic linking and `glew32s` is static. MinGW really does not like the dynamic (DLL) version of GLEW and you should probably avoid it. The pre-built Windows dynamic GLEW libraries that are distributed on the GLEW site will not work with MinGW because of differences between Visual C++ and gcc's function naming convention for import libraries (it is a difference of one underscore, but enough to make life really difficult).

If you `#define GLEW_STATIC` before including `<glew.h>` and link to `glew32s` that will eliminate any potential issues with the dynamic linking library. In practice, this works best if you add the definition to your Makefile as Nazar554 has demonstrated.

Answer (score -2):

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/mkhrystunov/b8c1600ab764403342b0) is how I compile OpenGL project in linux. Hope it helps